# Very complex query returns "Invalid object name 'IDList'" in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Works with Stimulsoft Report

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I´ve searched the forum for similar cases, tried what was suggested, to no avail. My query is a very long and complex one I use on a Stimulsoft report, and it works there. However, this query returns the error "Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 - Invalid object name 'IDList'" in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

I already preceeded the objects with the database name, like [WTData].[dbo].[objectnamehere], but that also did not work. I ensured the database WTData is selected as the active database in SQL studio.

What´s wrong with the object IDList in this query... I´m sorry but I have looked into this query for so long time that it´s not working of me anymore... Need a second eye to spot it...

If anyone can chime in to help, it will be very appreciated...

```
USE WTData
SELECT ToolLists.Ident, ToolLists.Descript AS TLDescript, ToolLists.MaterialNr, ToolLists.[Order], ToolLists.Who, ToolLists.NCP, ToolLists.Rem AS TLRem, ToolLists.TDate, ToolList.T, Machines.Name AS MachineName, Machines.TRelation, ToolList.D, ToolList.H, ToolList.Pos AS ToolListPos, ToolList.Rem AS ToolListRem, ToolList.How AS ToolListHow, Tools.Nr, Tools.Z1, Tools.Drawing, Tools.X1, Tools.Sort, Tools.Design, Tools.Descript, Tools.Rem AS ToolRem, ToolParts.Pos AS ToolPartPos, ToolPartPos, ToolParts.Nbr, ToolParts.How, Parts.UNr, Parts.Descript, Parts.Sort, Parts.Design, Parts.DMC, Parts.CLength, Parts.CMainArc, Parts.CRadius, Parts.UActiv, MatClasses.DMC, MatClasses.Description, MatClasses.Quality
FROM Parts INNER JOIN ((Machines RIGHT JOIN ((MatClasses RIGHT JOIN (Materials RIGHT JOIN (IDList INNER JOIN ToolLists ON IDList.ID = ToolLists.Nr) ON Materials.Nr = ToolLists.MaterialNr) ON MatClasses.Nr = Materials.MatClassNr) INNER JOIN (Tools INNER JOIN ToolList ON Tools.Nr = ToolList.ToolNr) ON ToolLists.Nr = ToolList.ToolListNr) ON Machines.Nr = ToolLists.MachineNr) INNER JOIN ToolParts ON Tools.Nr = ToolParts.ToolNr) ON Parts.ID = ToolParts.PartID
ORDER BY ToolLists.Nr, ToolList.Pos, ToolList.T
```

Comment: Have you tried without all those parentesis on the JOINs clauses! It is veeeery confusing and some, if not all, is not needed.

Comment: Hi Jorge... I guess the site messed up with my code after my first edit in the post... it should look correct now... The error is the same without the parenthesis...

Comment: Then your error is simple, you don't have a table called `IDList`

Comment: I don´t get how this query works within a Stimulsoft report... perhaps this table is created at runtime? Because I have the database here and indeed there´s no such table... Ok.. I´ll try to figure this out a little further... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. The name of the table in the database is WTDIDList - Stimulsoft changes the table name in query at the run time.